# jquery on click selector attach on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I usually handle click events for elements loaded with ajax like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".selector", function () { ...}
```

But in a specific case where i load content multiple times, somehow $(document) doesn't work, instead only works if i attach it to parent `$('.selector-parent').on("click", ".selector", function () { ...}`

Depending on the case, there isn't always a parent selector. Is it possible to attach it to document, and if selector exists use it, something like:

```
$(document, '.selector-parent').on("click", ".selector", function () { ...}
```

I don't want to set any if else to search if parent element exists, but to use it like this.

Comment: So you want to delegate the `click` handler to a parent element if the parent element exists, or to the `document`, if it does not? Without using an `if`? Why?

Comment: It must work with `$(document)`. Double check selector name, console and function execution.

Comment: i know it must work, but it doesn't, so can this be done in a way a need it, or similar?

Comment: @user4675957 if it doesn't work with `$(document)` there must be errors elsewhere on the page that's causing this not to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do something like this:

```
$('.selector-parent').add(document).on("click", ".selector", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e.delegateTarget);
});
```

Here is a little explanation. You select both parent element (which might not exist) and `document` into one collection using `add` method. After that you need to make sure event isn't handled twice by both `.selector-parent` and `document`, so whatever element processes it first, it stops event from further bubbling with `e.stopPropagation();`.

As the result, if there is no parent `.selector-parent` as the ancestor of the clicked `.selector`, the `document` will handle event. If `.selector-parent` exists it will do the job and `document` will not be used.

Check the demo below for how it works for both situations.

```js
$('.selector-parent').add(document).on("click", ".selector", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(e.delegateTarget.nodeName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selector-parent">
    <div class="selector">Parent exists</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="selector">No parent exists</div>
</div>
```